# Background process to update DB every few seconds with JSON data

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, timer

I am a complete novice with this but...

I have a small ASP MVC C# application reading an SQL database which I would like to be updated by a background process updating the DB with a JSON request potentially up to every minute or few seconds.

What is the best way to implement the background JSON DB update? In the MVC app on a persistent timer (is that even possible?) or independently (completely outside of the app) in a separate process with an executable running in the background with an internal programmatic timer or else using some kind of scheduler?

EDIT: For the sake of understanding - it is market prices in the JSON string that obviously need to be updated in the DB quite often ie potentially up to every few seconds if desirable or nessesary

Comment: Do you need to update the DB with JSON data, or are you using the JSON from the client to simply instruct the server to update the DB at a regular interval?

Comment: Yes, thank you Daniel, the database is to be updated by market prices contained in the JSON requested from the data provider every few seconds.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - is your MVC website actually a REST api that receives json requests from somewhere? If not can you provide a bit of information about how you get the json? I need to understand the source of information better to suggest a solution.

Comment: The MVC website will show records in the database. I am hoping to use jquery to auto refresh the web client with the latest DB updated prices every set number seconds maybe with a user refresh button as well.

The DB will be updated by market prices contained in a JSON fetch from the market prices provider which I also want to be auto request on a timer repeated every few seconds or so.

Comment: If your MVC site is displaying the market prices from the DB, then what is sending the json string with new market prices to update the DB? Do you have a web service which is separate from the MVC site which receives the json?

Comment: That's the question. How to go about updating the DB with the JSON string fetched from the market prices provider?

To be clear the DB and the MVC front end is mostly built but only with dummy data at the moment. 

I want to know what the best option is to make sure the DB is up to date with market prices so I thought I could write a program to run in the background on the server which would process the JSON string and parse the prices into the DB on a timer set for every minute or few seconds or so.

Sorry I'm not very good at explaining this.

Comment: In that case I would go for Wurd's answer; using a Windows Service. It can periodically fetch the json data for you and pump it into the DB as quickly as you need to.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. Good to get that confirmation. I was just putting together a rich picture of the system architecture to help people visualise what I mean.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Sf9qx1nwCyY1cxalJTRFVfRXc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [Windows Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76477d2t(v=vs.110).aspx) combined with the [Quartz.net](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) package.

You can run anything you want and on any schedule.

EDIT: From the above discussion I gather that your job would poll for market prices (a web request) that would run every few seconds and on getting the result would update your database.

EDIT2:

This would be your Quartz job:

```
public class FetchAndSaveFinancialData : IJob
{
   public void Execute()
   {
       //web request to get info

       //save to db
   }
}
```

Then your windows service base class:

```
public class YourFinancialServiceBase : ServiceBase
{
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {
      ServiceMain();
      base.OnStart(args);
   }
   protected override void OnStop()
   {
      base.OnStop();
   }
   protected void ServiceMain()
   {
       var scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();

       var job = JobBuilder.Create<FetchAndSaveFinancialData>().WithIdentity("Job1", "Group1").Build();

       ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("Trigger1","Group1")
           .StartNow()
           .WithSimpleSchedule(x=>x
             .WithIntervalInSeconds(5)
             .RepeatForever()
            ).Build();

       scheduler.ScheduleJob(job,trigger);

       scheduler.Start();
   }

}
```

EDIT3:

It all depends on what you use to access the data. If you plan on using EntityFramework then I would keep the MVC project and the WindowsService project in the same solution referencing a Library project. The library project would have all your models and allow you to see if changing something effects one or both components.

On the other hand if you rely a lot on stored procedures in your database the above is less relevant. You will have to consolidate any changes in your stored procedures more than in code.

In my experience, I'd rather have to sift through many projects in one solution than trying to find a completely different solution in a different language that is a critical part of your application.

Comment: Yes, kinda, here's a rich picture I put together to help communicate the system.

Thank you Wurd. Apparently, I'm not experienced enough to up tick anything, lol.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-Sf9qx1nwCyY1cxalJTRFVfRXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Simon See my edit. You only need to implement your actual getting and saving of the data.

Comment: that is very helpful thank you very much - I will go with that solution then - my cue signal to do some Quartz digging on youtube etc to get up to speed with it and implement your very clearly set out recommendation.

Comment: @Simon Remember to mark the answer as answered if it answered your question!

Comment: Have ticked your answer Wurd that's the only way I could find to approve it. Thanks again.

Comment: Thinking about your suggestion and different languages, Wurd, is there any reason why I couldnt use a completely separate technology outside of the MVC/C# app, as I already have some of the JSON request parsing done in both Python and VBA? 

I just need to make sure there are no data structure dependencies - but I think as long as the DB is frequently updated the MVC application doesnt need to know anything about that process since it is only reading the DB. 

If I did opt for Quartz as you suggest would I write it in the same project as the front end app using MVC or write direct to DB?

Comment: Thank you again Wurd. I agree it makes more sense to keep it all together and since this follow up question I have made some progress in understanding how it would integrate in the same solution in VS. 

Thank you again and to Daniel too - this has been enormously helpful and much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a way of implementing a Quartz solution here without using Windows Service? I have run into trouble with the windows service not being able to connect to the database despite my best efforts.

Would it be best to use Quartz or timers? As a reminder, the program reads a db for ID's, constructs a JSON request with those ID's, returns a JSON object with more information related to the ID's, and then updates them into the database. I would like to be able to repeat this cycle every 30 seconds or so.

Comment: I have only used Quartz with Windows Service because with ASP sites there is no guarantee that the site will be loaded. IIS automatically unloads or reloads sites at will and I don't know the compatibility between Quartz and ASP sites. I suggest you ask a new question or research this yourself, sorry! :)

Comment: Thank you, Wurd.

I have found this which seems promising in being able to do the job http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/591271/A-Simple-Scheduler-in-Csharp?msg=5302559#xx5302559xx

I got so frustrated at not being able to connect to the Db with windows service despite best efforts and asking on SO - that's the reason behind it just to reiterate.